# Throwing exceptions cannot convert from 'System.IO.DriveInfo' to 'string'

Tags: c#

I have tried to add Driverinfo into a listview but get error.

Here is my code what I have tried

```
using System.IO;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            lstdrive.Items.Add(di);
        }
    }
```

and the error is

> error Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.DriveInfo' to 'string'

Comment: Show all relevant code, e.g. where you define and assign `lstdrive`.

Answer (score 2):

Convert `DriveInfo di` to string

```
using System.IO;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            lstdrive.Items.Add(di.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: DriveInfo drive =(DriveInfo)lstdrive.SelectedItem;
                foreach (DriveInfo diInfo in drive.RootDirectory.GetDirectories())
                {
                    lstfolder.Items.Add(diInfo.ToString());
                }

Comment: what do you want to achieve @kumbhanibhavesh ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown where `lstdrive` is declared, but based on the error, my guess is it's a `List<string>`.  Thus, you can't add a `System.IO.DriveInfo` instance to it as you're trying to do with `di`.  Either convert the `di` to a string via `di.ToString()` or change your `lstdrive` declaration to `List<System.IO.DriveInfo>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume `lstdrive` is a `ListBox`

You will want to pick a property of the di object that you want to display in the list box.  Presumably that would be **Name**.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            lstdrive.Items.Add(di.Name);
        }
    }
```

Note that you could also use `di.ToString()` because the `DriveInfo` class overrides the `ToString()` method to emit the `Name` property as Mostafizur Rahman shows in his answer.

The following link has the link of properties available for a `DriveInfo` object.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

If you need other examples of how to use the DriveInfo class, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.110).aspx